Tableview inside cell Textfield - When keyboard appears top textfield of the text is removed
I am facing an issue,
how to fix the Tableview cell inside text field. Keyboard will show and dismiss textfield, top most of the tableview textfield text is getting an empty even user entered input.
Ex:
When I entered all the textfields and move to the last textfield - Then top most of the text field text is removed but original it should not be removed.
total sold value is textfield did end editing.
Crop name text is removed but it should not be done.
I used IQKeyboardmanager Swift

please edit your question to showcase the issue at hand, and add minimum reproducible code.

I'm not going to downvote, but without some code, I don't know what to suggest. I'm working on similar issues, right now.
